# How to supply hidden field value to node based on webform?

Tags: 8, webforms

Using D8 to create a node based on a Webform named "White Paper". I have a hidden field on the webform named white_paper_title.

When creating a node based on this form, I've added the following in the *Default webform submission data* field, like so:

```
white_paper_title: 'something'
```

This works fine if I base the new node on Webform, and select "White Paper" from the list.

The problem is that it never works when I create a new content type based on the White Paper webform. When viewing the node in the browser, the hidden field is there, but the value is never plugged in. How do I get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a field's value as a token to the webform.

You would need to add 'field_white_paper_title' to your webform node and then change the "Default webform submission data (YAML)" to

```
white_paper_title: [webform_submission:node:field_white_paper_title]
```

Comment: But will the [webform_submission] have anything in it before the webform is submitted by the visitor?

Comment: The [webform_submission:node:*] token is not pulling data from the submission but the node that submission is being posted from.

Comment: I still have the problem about why I can pass YAML to a node based on a general Webform, but not on a node based on my particular webform.

Comment: Yep that is a bug. It took me second to understand that a custom webform was not working as expected.  I created this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2841583 on D.O to address the problem.

Comment: This issue has been fixed. (https://www.drupal.org/node/2841583) Please download or checkout the latest dev release.